# Unable to download wine with software center or terminal

Tags: command-line, wine, software-center

I'm trying to download wine 1.7 with the software center and terminal, 3 MB remained of download progress , but when i want to continue the download , it gives me a 404 error. i rebooted the system many times and checked my Internet connection, but still the same problem. Does anyone knows why ?

**This is the error I'm getting:**

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgl1-mesa-glx i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgles2-mesa i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libwayland-egl1-mesa i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libegl1-mesa-drivers i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libglapi-mesa i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libegl1-mesa i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libosmesa6 i386 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa-drivers_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglapi-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**running apt-get update gives me this**

```
root@ArshiaAghaei:~# apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable InRelease [1,540 B]                          
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 1,540 B] [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to security.uSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stabIgn http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Now , I dn't see the Install button in software center.

Comment: is that possible to show the 404 error message detail?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9832556/

Comment: Have you tried different mirror?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the literature, HTML 404 error means that your computer can communicate with the remote server but the server can not provide the file that is requested. It seams that the internet connection is OK.

The solution would be mentioned in your error message as:

```
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Make sure that your system is updated and install the other necessary modules.

For more detail tutorial, please check this:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-wine-1-7-20-ubuntu-linux/

Good Luck

Comment: I tried apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade , but the first one fails and i see errors in the second one.

Comment: I had put this problem in the chatting room. Hope for geek user to help. Just do your best. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps:

1. Open up Terminal.
2. Type `cd /etc/apt`
3. Type `sudo gedit sources.list`
4. In the editor, replace all the country domain names with your country domain. For instance, if you have lines like following:

   > deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
   >   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

replace `us` with `your_country_domain` in the http link. If you are from UK then replace `us` with `uk` in the link. Replace every occurrence of `us` to your's in the file. Note that, if `us` doesn't exist, no problem. Just replace whatever there is with the your country domain.

5. Save the file and exit the editor.
6. Now, proceed with the process.

Comment: Can you explain more ???

Comment: YOU DESTROYED MY ENTIRE SYSTEM !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WHAT THE HELL IS YOUR PROBLEM ?????!!!!
ARE YOU CRAZY ??????!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: WHAT THE HELL CAN I DO NOW ?????!!!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it would haven't destroyed your PC. I'm too had the same problem and solved by the same method. I have no idea of the way you have done.

Comment: @ArshiaAghaei If it made the question worse please edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: I JUST DONE WHAT YOU SAID.
I gave this link to someone and he said HE DESTROYED YOUR SYSTEM HARDLY

Comment: What was happened after you did so? By the way, could I know which country you are from?